# SQL trigger giving error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to call a stored procedure to create multiple rows using some of the cell values of the new row inserted in the table resource but I'm getting an error. Here is my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `details` AFTER INSERT ON `resource` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
CALL addcopies(NEW.copies, NEW.id, NEW.location);
END;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `details` AFTER INSERT ON `resource` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL addcopies(NEW.copies, NEW.id, NEW.location);
END
|
delimiter ;
```

If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`